# JDBC connection can't cast error

Tags: java, jdbc

I am facing a problem while connecting to database

error message:

> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection cannot be cast to com.sun.corba.se.pept.transport.Connection

What does it indicate?

Comment: Maybe if you showed the code where you are creating the objects?

Comment: Did you import the wrong `Connection` class?

Comment: it indicates that `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` cannot be cast to `com.sun.corba.se.pept.transport.Connection`, most likely your imports are wrong.

Comment: Maybe you are provided one driver and want to work with another.

Comment: Please specify which database you're trying to connect. And also the statements related to the Connection instances and the import statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.sun.corba.se.pept.transport.Connection` is a communication interface, not a database interface.

Change your class reference to `java.sql.Connection`